# cmake error : opencv2/opencv.hpp：opencv2/opencv.hpp：No such file or directory

Tags: linux, opencv, ubuntu, cmake

I am compiling opencv programs with cmake.
   The code is as follows:

DisplayImage.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;
int main(int argc, char** argv )
{
    if ( argc != 2 )
    {
        printf("usage: DisplayImage.out <Image_Path>\n");
        return -1;
    }

    Mat image;
    image = imread( argv[1], 1 );

    if ( !image.data )
    {
        printf("No image data \n");
        return -1;
    }
    namedWindow("Display Image", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow("Display Image", image);

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project( DisplayImage )

set(OpenCV_DIR /home/lmk/opencv-3.1.0/release)

include_directories( ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )

target_link_libraries( DisplayImage ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

I put the DisplayImage.cpp and CMakeLists.txt in the folder called test in my personal home folder, namely `/home/lmk/test/`.
   Then I use command lines :

> lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:~/test$ mkdir build
>   lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:~/test$ cd build
>   lmk@lmk-virtual-machine:~/test/build$ cmake ..

Which give me:

> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0 
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.3.0 
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc 
>   -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works 
>   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info 
>   -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done 
>  
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ 
>   -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works 
>   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info 
>   -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done 
>   -- Configuring done 
>   -- Generating done 
>   -- Build files have been written to: /home/lmk/test/build

But when I use:

> Scanning dependencies of target DisplayImage
>   [100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o
>   /home/lmk/test/DisplayImage.cpp:2:30: fatal eror：opencv2/opencv.hpp：No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated. 
>   make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o] Error 1
>
>   make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/all] Error 2
>   make: *** [all] Error 1

Do you konw why?
   I am using opencv 3.1.0 and cmake 2.8.12.2 in the terminal of ubuntu 14.04 in VM!

Comment: I have solved the error by modiflying the CMakeLists.txt : `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

project( DisplayImage )

set(OpenCV_DIR /home/lmk/opencv-3.1.0/release)

include_directories( /usr/local/opencv-3.1.0/include )

add_executable( DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp )

target_link_libraries( DisplayImage /usr/local/opencv-3.1.0/lib )
`. But new error exists: **`DisplayImage.cpp:(.text+0x34)：undefined reference to ‘cv::imread(cv::String const&, int)’ `**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the 'typical' way, using `find_package()`?

Try to repeat the steps in [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html) tutorial, and report what is happening.

Comment: `find_package()`? Can you tell me in details? I installed my opencv 3.1.0 in /usr/local/opencv-3.1.0. This is the first time I use cmake to compile.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old, so I had to build OpenCV 2 from source:

```
$ git clone --depth 1 --branch 2.4.13.7 https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
$ cmake -S opencv -B opencv-build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DWITH_CUDA=NO -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$PWD/opencv-install
$ cmake --build opencv-build
$ cmake --install opencv-build
```

Then I wrote the following CMakeLists.txt for your code:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(test)

find_package(OpenCV 2 REQUIRED)

add_executable(DisplayImage DisplayImage.cpp)
target_link_libraries(DisplayImage PRIVATE ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

To build this, I simply ran:

```
$ cmake -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DOpenCV_ROOT=$PWD/opencv-install
...
$ cmake --build build/ --verbose
[1/2] /usr/bin/c++  -I/path/to/opencv-install/include/opencv -I/path/to/opencv-install/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o -c /path/to/DisplayImage.cpp
[2/2] : && /usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  CMakeFiles/DisplayImage.dir/DisplayImage.cpp.o -o DisplayImage  -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/opencv-install/lib  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_videostab.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_ts.a  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_superres.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_stitching.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_contrib.so.2.4.13  -ldl  -lm  -lpthread  -lrt  -ldl  -lm  -lpthread  -lrt  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_ocl.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_gpu.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_photo.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_legacy.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_video.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_ml.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_features2d.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_flann.so.2.4.13  ../opencv-install/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.4.13 && :
```

If you have OpenCV installed in a standard system location, then `-DOpenCV_ROOT=$PWD/opencv-install` is unnecessary.